# python pandas how to apply inplace = True for replace data and get updated csv

Tags: python, pandas

I want to keep change updated data and download the csv. how to do that in pandas here is my code:

```
data = pd.read_csv("product.csv")  
data['image'] = data['image'].str.strip("[]'")
data["image"]=data["image"].str.split(",")
```

But I am getting old value when type data in my console. how to keep change updated value and download the csv?

Comment: `.str.strip("[]'")`. You have a single quote at the right to the square brackets.

Comment: pls post a sample dataframe and expected output from it

Comment: I have single quote because I have single quote in my string and I am removing single quote from my all row

Answer (score 0):

Pandas does not modify CSV files in place.

Have you simply forgotten to save your DataFrame?

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("product.csv")
data['image'] = data['image'].str.strip("[]'").str.split(',')
data.to_csv('product.csv')
```